# NDVI Calculation from Satellite Data

Tags: python

I have 9 raster images for 9 different months. These images represent NDVI values for a location. I am trying to get the the average NDVI value for each month and organize them in a table in ArcGIS Pro? I attempted to use the code below to automate the process using Phython window in ArcGIS Pro:

```py
# Set the workspace and mosaic dataset name
workspace = r"C:\Users\4401abiye\OneDrive - Wanlan Geo\Desktop\Abori\GSI_Remote Sensing\Ishaga_RemoteSensingData\Data_Analysis\Clipped_NDVI\Bailey.gdb"
mosaic_dataset_name = "Bailey_NDVI_Mosaic"

# Create a new mosaic dataset with the desired coordinate system
coordinate_system = arcpy.SpatialReference("NAD 1983 (2011) UTM Zone 15N")
arcpy.CreateMosaicDataset_management(workspace, mosaic_dataset_name, coordinate_system)

# Add raster images to the mosaic dataset
raster_folder = r"C:\Users\4401abiye\OneDrive - Wanlan Geo\Desktop\Abori\GSI_Remote Sensing\Ishaga_RemoteSensingData\Data_Analysis\Clipped_NDVI\Bailey"
arcpy.AddRastersToMosaicDataset_management(mosaic_dataset_name, "Raster Dataset", raster_folder)

# Open the attribute table of the mosaic dataset
attribute_table = arcpy.Describe(mosaic_dataset_name).catalogPath + "\\AT"

# Add a "Month" field to store the month values
arcpy.AddField_management(attribute_table, "Month", "TEXT")

# Populate the "Month" field based on raster names
expression = "!Name!.split('_')[1]"  # Assuming the raster names follow a specific naming convention
arcpy.CalculateField_management(attribute_table, "Month", expression, "PYTHON")

# Add a field to store average NDVI values
arcpy.AddField_management(attribute_table, "Avg_NDVI", "DOUBLE")

# Calculate the average NDVI value for each month
expression = "arcpy.Raster.mean(!Name!)"
arcpy.CalculateField_management(attribute_table, "Avg_NDVI", expression, "PYTHON")

# Save the attribute table as a standalone table
output_table = r"C:\Users\4401abiye\OneDrive - Wanlan Geo\Desktop\Abori\GSI_Remote Sensing\Ishaga_RemoteSensingData\Data_Analysis\Clipped_NDVI\Bailey\BaileyNDVI_table.dbf"

arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(attribute_table, workspace, output_table)
```

---

But I am getting this error:

```markdown
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 15042, in CreateMosaicDataset
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 15039, in CreateMosaicDataset
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.CreateMosaicDataset_management(*gp_fixargs((in_workspace, in_mosaicdataset_name, coordinate_system, num_bands, pixel_type, product_definition, product_band_definitions), True)))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 520, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
 ERROR 000732: Output Location: Dataset C:\Users\4401abiye\OneDrive - Wanlan Geo\Desktop\Abori\GSI_Remote Sensing\Ishaga_RemoteSensingData\Data_Analysis\Clipped_NDVI\Bailey.gdb does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (CreateMosaicDataset).
```

I am thinking about the continuation line maybe the backlash character is wrong. Or remove the line continuation character and keep the path in a single line or use raw string literal for the file path. Not too sure